# How can i view 1 selection line in PickerView?

Tags: ios, uipickerview

when pickerview scrolling other items showing blur above and below selectline

How do I get just select single line?

Comment: Please explain your Question properly.

Comment: it is default behavior of pickerView  in iOS7. => (blur above and below) and also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20137284/removing-non-selected-items-from-uipickerview

Comment: You want to remove the blur?

Comment: joao // yes i want remove the blur i want view just selection 1 row not blur above and belows

Comment: blur view wasting space for nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi use this one to get the value of selected row of picker.

```
NSInteger pickerRow;
NSArray *arrayData;
UIPickerView *picker;

pickerRow = [picker selectedRowInComponent:0];
self.yourString = [repeatPickerData objectAtIndex:row];
```

thanks

Comment: thanks for answer. but i want remove blur views in picker view , not the value

Comment: Can u please add a screenshot of it?

Comment: I will provide the solution for the same.Thanks

Comment: Actually if you are using the ios7 then the picker have a look in this link:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/Controls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH9-SW1

Comment: yes ios7 how can i view 1 row without blur things

Comment: <Solved>

just cover ui picker view's above and below blur parts with ui scroll view